cant print api key from env even after using os.getenv
I wanted to see if I had any issues with my setup of env.
I used python in Vscode
Here is my code:
import os 
import requests

from dotenv import load_dotenv, dotenv_values
load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv("myKey")

print('hi')
print(api_key)

But it is constantly returning "None" for my API key.
Notes:
The python file and .env file are in the same directory
Everything is installed properly
No error messages
I also tried only importing load_dotenv instead of oing both dotenv_values as well
Checking directory
Pip install and uninstall needed modules
Switching python interpreters, although I run into errors when using python 3.12.1 instead of 3.11.0, both are 64 bit.

load_dotenv() will look in the current directory for the .env file, which is not necessarily the same directory as the python script file.  You can use this short code to display the current directory import os; print(os.getcwd())

@JohnGordon thank you for your response.  upon using print(os.getcwd()) the out displayed is telling me the directory of the folder in which both my python and .env file are both stored, however, the issue at hand persists,

Are you sure you saved the .env file after editing it?

How are you running this code? You mentioned "I used python in Vscode", are you perhaps using VS Code's debugger configuration for running Python?

@GinoMempin I just clicked the play button and "run python file" I don't think I'm using the code debugger

@JohnGordon yeah I saved it

Have you tried printing os.environ, to see if it contains any of the vars from the .env file?

Does your actual environment contain a blank/null value for that key?  load_dotenv() won't override existing variables unless you tell it to.

@JohnGordon I'm not sure about that, I do know however that I have not ever set a blank/null value for the key. Instead, I've put the key in the env folder as myKey=myapikey

This code is correct.  My only guess is that you've made some other mistake.  Either the .env file is located in some other directory, or the .env file has the wrong contents, or you didn't save it, or the key name is wrong, or some other detail that depends on your local environment which we cannot see.

This code will show you the actual contents of the .env file in the current directory.  Try it print(dotenv_values(".env")) Is the expected key listed in the output?

Have you tried running this file directly from the terminal? Not using VS Code or any IDE. Just open a terminal on the directory with this python script and the .env, and then just directly run python <filename>.py from that folder? If that works, then there is nothing wrong with the code or the .env file, and there is something else.
